# How to unmap vim shortcuts upon quickfix exits

Tags: vim

**Background**: I'm using [skwp's dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles), and his recently [changes](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/commit/cf6bb61336ebc96e4654c16b4a317d7fba66511d#diff-26365e078b9a0f783c79e406f260c8a7) is breaking some functionalities I use on daily basis.

Instead of set up the mappings globally, I'm trying to `nnoremap` two shortcuts upon quickfix enters and `nunmap` after quickfixes quits.

*BTW*, I think [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) is used for linting, which invokes the quickfix/location lists.

Here's the code:

```
augroup quickfixShortcutsGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWrite * :echom "Foo"
  " au BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <silent> <C-z> :cp<CR>
  " au BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <silent> <C-x> :cn<CR>
  au BufWinEnter quickfix nnoremap <silent> <C-z> :cp<CR>
  au BufWinEnter quickfix :echo '1'
  au BufWinLeave quickfix nnoremap <silent> <C-z> :cp<CR>
  au BufWinLeave quickfix :echo 'BufWinLeave'
  au BufLeave qf :echo 'BufLeave'
  au BufUnload qf :echo 'unload qf'
  " au BufLeave qf noremap <silent> <C-z> :cb<CR>
  " au BufLeave quickfix noremap <silent> <C-z> :cb<CR>
  " au BufWinLeave quickfix noremap <silent> <C-z> :cb<CR>
  " au BufWinLeave quickfix nunmap <C-z>
  " au BufWinLeave quickfix :echom 'Hello'<cr>
  " BufWinEnter
augroup END
```

After read reference:

1. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWinLeave
2. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-patterns

I still could not get `unmap` events working, i.e. `BufWinLeave`, `BufUnload`, `BufLeave` are not invoked.

Can Vimers tell me which event(s) I should be using and help me out on this? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Use a `ftplugin` for `qf` instead of all those `autocmd`s, and add `<buffer>` to mappings to make them local to the quickfix buffer.

Comment: "Background: I'm using skwp's dotfiles, and his recently changes is breaking some functionalities I use on daily basis." What a surprise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `:help BufWinLeave` explains, *the current buffer "%" may be different from the buffer being unloaded ""*. So you need a global autocmd, and resolve the buffer number that has been left, and then check for the *quickfix* `'buftype'`:

```
autocmd! BufWinLeave * if getbufvar(bufnr(expand('<afile>')), '&buftype') ==# 'quickfix' | echo "leaving quickfix" | endif
```

But in general, I'd advise against such tricks and especially conditional mappings. Your `<C-z>` / `<C-x>` mappings are still global, now just depending on whether the quickfix list is visible. That's bad for muscle memory, and the overload of the key combos is mentally taxing. I'd rather get rid of the mappings completely, or assign different (if potentially longer) keys.

And there's the next complication: Vim "distributions" and other people's dotfiles lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to `nnoremap` these two mappings upon quickfix enters and `nunmap` after quickfix quits, you could

```
" map silently upon entering Quickfix
autocmd BufWinEnter * if &buftype == 'quickfix' 
    \| nnoremap <silent> <C-x> :cn<CR>
    \| nnoremap <silent> <C-z> :cp<CR>
    \| endif

" unmap upon leaving Quickfix
autocmd BufWinLeave * if &buftype == 'quickfix' 
    \| nunmap <C-x>
    \| nunmap <C-z>
    \| endif
```

Or you can make use of local buffer mapping to make your code shorter

```
" map silently upon entering Quickfix, and only for Quickfix
autocmd BufWinEnter * if &buftype == 'quickfix' 
    \| nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-x> :cn<CR>
    \| nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-z> :cp<CR>
    \| endif
```

These `autocmd`'s are invoked every time you enter or leave a buffer. So it is really better just, as [Sato Katsura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4959010/sato-katsura) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622459/how-to-unmap-vim-shortcuts-upon-quickfix-exits#comment55021384_33622459), add in your `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim`

```
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-x> :cn<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-z> :cp<CR>
```

You may consider to read these:

- [`:h ftplugins`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#add-filetype-plugin)
- [`:h map-local`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-local)
- [`:h buftype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27buftype%27)
- [`:h line-continuation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#line-continuation)